# Problem in Activity with Spinner and ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity has a spinner and a custom ListView and they are both sourced by custom ArrayAdapters (ArrayList of custom objects).  The ListView rows are custom views (just 2 TextViews).

When I include the line, spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); the ListView is NOT filled with data on the screen and the spinner contains the values I want.

When I remove the line, spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); the ListView is filled with the data I want and the spinner does NOT contain any values.

When I debug, I see the data in the ListView's custom ArrayAdapter variable and the spinner's custom ArrayAdapter.

I have checked my getView() implementation for the ListView's custom ArrayAdapter class.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste some code to help identify the problem. I tested with two listviews and a spinner pointing to the same adapter. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I solved the issue on my own by redesigning the classes.